# Moving files using sftp

Tags: shell-scripting

I am trying to move files from one location to another on the remote server using sftp below:

```
for i in a b c d
do
sftp $REMUSR <<EOM>>$OUT 2>&1
rename $SOURDIR/sample_${i}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz $REMDIR
quit
EOM
:
:
done
```

but i get the message

```
Couldn't rename file "/source/sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz" to       "/destin/": No such file or directory
```

though this file exists under the /source directory which i verified:

```
ls -l sample_a_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz
-rw-r--r--  1 prd admin 112 May 23 09:16 sample_a_20140330.gz
```

Pls help

Comment: If you want to write a bash script, then I would suggest to use `scp` instead as it will allow you to pass it bash variables

Comment: @edvinas.me How does that work ? Doesn't the op want to move a remote file into a remote directory (at least that's the way I read it)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to supply a destination file name

```
sftp> rename f destin/
Couldn't rename file "/home/iain/s" to "/home/iain/destin/": No such file or directory
sftp> rename f destin/s
```

I did a quick search and it doesn't look like there is a clean solution to this.

Comment: Alternative would be to use `scp` which would allow to pass it bash variables

Comment: Am supposed to use sftp only for this, sadly. If I'm sure of having the required files under /source, can something like rename $SOURDIR/* $REMDIR be used atleast to move everything to /destin?

Comment: rename is the same as mv - the deistination can be a dirctory name

Answer (score 0):

first, it looks like you are missing a destination on the remote host
next, it looks as if you are trying to rename a directory to a file. if you *are* trying to rename a directory, try using the full path, and not use a trailing "/" (ex. rename /home/mydir /home/otherdir )

Also, it looks like the command is seeing the regex as an actual filename (based on the quotes around it, in your error message) try enclosing the command in the script in backticks "`".

Remember, just because you are executing on a remote server, the commands are being interpeted locally.

Another possibility is to use batch mode to run the commands, rather than the <> method you are using.

Answer (score 0):

sftp can't see the remote filenames to process the globbing,  use ssh with mv instead:

```
 ssh $REMUSR mv $SOURDIR/sample_${i}_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].gz $REMDIR"
```

here the implied remote shell process will do the globing and pass the results to mv